# Why socialauth is giving class cast exception on provided parameter map?

Tags: java, classcastexception, socialauth

SocialAuth [getting started guide](http://code.google.com/p/socialauth/wiki/GettingStarted) have following code sample:

```
  // get the auth provider manager from session
  SocialAuthManager manager = (SocialAuthManager)session.getAttribute("authManager");

  // call connect method of manager which returns the provider object. 
  // Pass request parameter map while calling connect method. 
   AuthProvider provider = manager.connect(paramsMap);

  // get profile
  Profile p = provider.getUserProfile();

  // you can obtain profile information
  System.out.println(p.getFirstName());

  // OR also obtain list of contacts
  List<Contact> contactsList = provider.getContactList();
```

The comment at line 3-4 say that we should pass the request parameter map to `manager.connect()`. I tried:

```
manager.connect(request.getParameterMap());
```

But it gives

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.String; cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

Should I create my own parameter map instead of passing map returned by `request.getParameterMap()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question:

The socialauth source have a sample with following code:

```
Map<String, String> paramsMap = SocialAuthUtil.getRequestParametersMap(request);            
AuthProvider provider = manager.connect(paramsMap);
```

Which fixes the classcastexception